# How to display multiple values in single TextBox with comma separate

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I am Facing one Problem in SSRS report,i have one field ImportEntryNo in this field values are like A004C11A,B005C12,C1121X,AC00102,etc this values i want display in the Header section in text box same like above with comma separate in one line or two lines,and if any values are duplicated i want display single value for that duplicated value.Please can any one help me.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the join function in a text box to create your list, however I cannot think of a way in ssrs to remove your duplicates.

=join(fields!column.value, ",")